# How do I find songs in my iTunes library that aren’t associated with my Apple ID?

Tags: itunes, music, apple-id

I get messages when syncing my iPod that tell me that a song cannot be copied because I am not authorised to play them.

Is there a quick way to find all songs that are like this and delete them?

Comment: You can make a Smart Playlist that just finds Purchased items, and then there’s a field called “iCloud Status” – perhaps you could find them by filtering with that field?

Answer (score 2):

First, why not authorise your computer? **Store** → **Authorise This Computer…** and log in.

Whilst you can't distinguish between songs for an authorised Apple ID and an unauthorised Apple ID, you can create a smart playlist that shows Purchased songs.

[image]

Comment: Is this the best method? Unfortunately the songs in question had been authorised by a friend of mine with another apple id and i have quite a number of songs in my library (2118) that have been purchased through the itunes store. I am only trying to find about 13 songs out of that total number so even with the cut down numbers it will take me quite some time.

Comment: Sorting by date added, genre, Year, etc. can help reduce the search further.

Comment: There’s srsly still no easy way? I’ve got thousands of songs from CDs and iTunes purchases, and there are about 2 from oooold friends that snuck though the last time I pulled from a portable hard drive. SO SICK of my phone constantly asking me enter their password.